# DelayBind not binding MvxCommands within MvxTableViewCell on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an `ItemCell` which inherits from `MvxTableViewCell`. Below is simplified:

**Constructor**:

```
public ItemCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
    CreateLayout();
    InitializeBindings();
}
```

`CreateLayout()` creates and constrains, among other elements:

- A `UILabel` `_label`, and
- A `UIButton` `_button`

**InitializeBindings**:

```
private void InitializeBindings()
{
    this.DelayBind(() =>
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ItemCell, ItemViewModel>();

        set.Bind(_label).For(x => x.Text).SourceDescribed("'Label: ' + ItemNumber");
        set.Bind(_button).To(vm => vm.ItemCommand);

        set.Apply();
    });
}
```

**ViewModel** contains the following property and command:

```
private string _itemNumber;
public string ItemNumber
{
    get { return _itemNumber; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _itemNumber, value); }
}

private IMvxCommand _itemCommand;
public IMvxCommand ItemCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _itemCommand?? (_itemCommand= new MvxCommand(() => {
            //Logic
        }));
    }
 }
```

When the `TableView` is bound to a collection and the cells are repeated, `_label`'s text renders the correct value ("Label: {ItemNumber}"), but clicking the button doesn't hit the `ItemCommand`'s `get`. I have also tried adding `.For("TouchUpInside")` to the button's binding, but that didn't change anything.

I'm confused as to why the label binds correctly, but the button does not.

Comment: Is there something in the Debug output?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe No, nothing relevant to the bindings during page load, and nothing is printed to the window when I click the button.

Comment: We have this problem from time to time. But it was never a binding problem. In our case it happened, when the button was visible but had size 0. You can see the text, but can't interact. Could you please ensure, that the button is layouted correctly and not overlapped by another view!?

Comment: Not sure on IOS but on Android you have to bind the itemCommand to the itemClick property of the list, not of the cell.

Comment: Do you have `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` file in iOS project? to deal with Xamarin.iOS linker

Comment: try deleting the DelayBind, use just var set.. set.Apply()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have enough points to add a comment so I'll add my suggestion as an answer.

What possibly might be happening is that your **touch event** is handled for the **whole cell** and therefore the **event is not passed down to the children** of that cell. Your button might be **bound correctly** but since your button within your cell will **never receive the touch event** the command which you bound to will **never get fired**.

**EDIT**

You can have a look at this link which seems to address your problem.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15560/how-to-add-a-custom-button-in-a-table-cell

Comment: This link was helpful; essentially the entire MvxTableViewCell was capturing the click event, and the click events on the items contained inside it were never fired. Binding was actually working, but the clicks were not. 

Setting the `AllowsSelection` property of your UITableView to 'false' allows the cell's children to receive and handle click events.

Answer (score 0):

Debug output (Mvx.Trace()) the Bounds of your UIButton. Even if it is displayed, its "bounds" may be 0. In this case, no interaction can occur on it, and you have to fix your layout (constraints or frame).